# Can't join two tables on a foreign key field using django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class weapons(models.Model):
    weapon = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    country = models.IntegerField()
    flags = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class compare(models.Model):
    weapon = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    flags = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    WeaponNode = models.ForeignKey(weapons, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When I run this function:

```
compare.objects.filter(user_id=1).values_list('weapon', 'WeaponNode__title')
```

I expect this query raw:

```
SELECT apps_compare.weapon, apps_weapons.title FROM apps_compare INNER JOIN apps_weapons ON (apps_compare.weapon = apps_weapons.weapon) WHERE apps_compare.user_id = 1
```

Result should be:

[image]

But it returns this instead:

```
SELECT "apps_compare"."weapon", "apps_weapons"."title" FROM "apps_compare" INNER JOIN "apps_weapons" ON ("apps_compare"."WeaponNode_id" = "apps_weapons"."id") WHERE "apps_compare"."user_id" = 1
```

apps_weapons.title returns null:

[image]

In other examples I saw, they only used id with JOIN ON but I want to use a weapon value instead of id. How can I do accomplish with ORM? If it's not possible with ORM, then what are the other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You are here using the `ForeignKey` the wrong way. If the `weapon` in your `Compare` model refers to `weapon`s in the `Weapon` model, it should be unique, and then use that as a [**`to_field=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field):

```
class Weapon(models.Model):
    weapon = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    # …

class Compare(models.Model):
    weapon = models.ForeignKey(
        Weapon,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        to_field='weapon',
        db_column='weapon'
    )
    # …
```

Then you can query with:

```
Compare.objects.values('weapon', 'weapon__title')
```